# Can you publish a single chapter of a manga series?

Tags: publishing, comics

Can you publish a single chapter of a manga series? I am guessing yes, but I don't see manga chapters being sold separately on Amazon. I see comics issue being sold, but it seems issues are sold for collection purpose. But I don't see webcomics and manga chapters being sold separately. I see them being sold as volumes, roughly 500 pages, so I am wondering how do you navigate this as an author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are allowed to sell anything legal on Amazon, as long as you aren't defrauding or misleading people.

Another route is the website "Patreon", people "subscribe" for a small monthly fee of your choice; to support you (including artists), in return for you posting your created content online for them to enjoy. They can cancel their subscription at any time. Most artists post a combination of totally free stuff and subscriber-only stuff. I subscribe to a channel there, for $5 a month.

How you get the word out is up to you; of course. The artist I subscribe to began by posting You-Tube videos; and asking for people to join their Patreon channel.

I'm not sure, but you might be able to sell some intro chapters on Amazon or Apple Store for very cheap or free, and advertise your Patreon channel using those, if not directly then in the content itself. Then you could build yourself a subscriber base. Good luck.

Comment: Is there any reason why it's never done?

Comment: @Sayaman I know it is done with free games on Apple Store. As for other content, I am not sure, I haven't done a survey of Patreon or other sites. But I imagine if it is not done, it is just market dynamics. How much will you pay for a single chapter of a book? $1? The first Harry Potter book had 17 chapters; and I bought a new copy for $4.99. About 29c per chapter. I bought a science fiction book with 28 chapters recently for $7.99. About 29c per chapter. I'm not sure an unknown author will get many takers at a higher price. Perhaps $5 a year, with 6 chapters of free proven content...

Comment: The webcomic artists I followed over the years usually spread their work for free on all channels available to them to draw people to either their Patreon, their merch shop, or both. Cross-promotion is also very common among webcomic artists.

Comment: @Philipp Makes sense, Patreon is much like free Magazine publishing; people can make a decent living even at subscription rates of $1 month. (Patreon pricing: https://www.patreon.com/pricing), It will cost them $0.15 for each donation; so they only get $0.85, but multiply that by 5000 patrons = $4250/month. The battle is building up followers, plain and simple. A lot of them, maybe 95%, will fall away once you put a price on the work, but that's fine, if you capture 5% of the market that's a business. Publish 12 month old stuff for free, get the latest for $1/month.